# Tasks the Gulp way

Tags: gulp

I want to automate some deployment tasks using gulp.
the things I need to do are:

Given some set of configurations do the following:

```
 1. Copy some predetermined set of files  
 2. For each config   
    2.1 Override some of those files with files from an origin based on the current config
    2.2 Modify some specific files (regexp Search & Replace) based on the current config  
    2.3 zip the current set of files into some (config based) file.zip
```

The original source files should not be modified by this process.

I am almost sure that I am not expressing this "the gulp way"...
What would be the appropriate way (and existing modules/plugins to use) to write such a task / set of tasks using Gulp ?

Comment: In general, write functions to achieve mini-tasks and return streams or a promise out of them, then combine those function is a `gulp` stream. In general every time I have to write a task in `gulp` I first go in the [recipes](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes) folder to check whether there's a best practice for that (or to see **what's the gulp way** for it).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the recipes folder. Still My problem is that I feel that am not sure how to think of those "file streams". I sort of think the answer I am looking for would change the flow logic into something else that works better with streaming.